# HttpContext.User property is getting null with large Json Get requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using a custom authorize attribute in my MVC 4 web site which acts as a global action filter. Code is pretty pretty simple like below:

```
 public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            var user = Membership.GetUser(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, true);

            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || user == null || !user.IsApproved || user.IsLockedOut|| !System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser().Any() )
            {
                HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
}
```

This works absolutely fine but in one of the action methods in my application which is called by  $.getJSON request  filterContext.HttpContext.User property is getting null.  I am sending a concatenated string in the data parameter with my getJson request, if the length of this string is large then only I'm facing this issue otherwise I never receive null User. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: This is probably a setting on your server. There is typically a maximum response size. Have you looked in Firebug to see if the response is actually getting to the browser?

Comment: just check instead of $.getJson() use $.post() becoz $.getJson() gives problem for larger data string...

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla, [No it doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915366/getjson-not-working-for-large-data). getJson is just a wrapper for ajax. The same code is executed underneath

Comment: use post the required code here...

Comment: Hi Kartikeya, request is going to server in a get request but on the server as my CustomAthorizeAttribute executes at the very begining where I get the error I am unable to check what is happening with the Json data on the server. How to check it on the server any idea?

Comment: just show here where do you applied custom athorize attribute in ur controller????

Comment: [HttpGet]
        [CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Investigator,Supervisor,Manager,Viewer")]
        [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Cache1Minute", VaryByParam = "EventPage;FromDateTime;ToDateTime;SiteId;TagName")]
        public JsonResult GetEventsGrid(OperationalStatusParamViewModel paramModel)

Comment: Json call is like this   $.getJSON(window.appRoot + "OperationalStatus/GetEventsGrid", paramData, function (d) {------}